Upgrade from php 5.5 to php 8 error (string * int) fix in common
Having a 15-year-old project in hand now with Yii 1.1 and PHP 5.4. After a big decision, planned to upgrade the PHP version 8.0.30 and keep running the project, and almost achieved it.
After upgrading, I fixed some config and related deprecated functions and successfully ran it on the server. But in some pages/functions, I got this error:
Exception 1 : round(): Argument #1 ($num) must be of type int|float, string given
Exception 2 : Unsupported operand types: string * int
I produced a fix like below,
For Exception 1:
return round($number, 5);

to: (type casting)
return round((float)$number, 5);

For Exception 2:
return ($a + 10);

to: (type cast)
return ((float)$a + 10);

And the error ceased.
It would happen on other files/functions too. Because the project contains almost 4000+ files
So, I want to know, is there some actual solution instead of changing manually in all files with type mismatch?
Updated with the error that I got for Exception 2. Got the error like below,


PHP should still type-juggle this just fine. See: https://3v4l.org/eW35Q What are the exact circumstances under which you get these messages?

4000 of your own files, or is that including Yii?  If it is an old Yii install upgrading that would surely fix those problems.  Note that round((int)$number, 5); does not make any sense - int will remove the fractional part entirely, defeating the purpose.

Do you perhaps have strict typing enabled somehow?

Hi @KiKO Software. But it throws me an error screen.  So why, I asked as a question here.

It's good practice to go through and fix those problems. Such a major PHP version bump will not be painless. It is possible that these things are warnings but you have strict error reporting so warnings show as errors but even so you should not change this.

Hi @Don't Panic, 4000 files are in the project without including Yii files. And I just used (int) for reference here. I temporarily fixed it on my function by using round(floatval($a), 2)

Also according to this your error is that you are passing a string that cannot be juggled to a float. The docs mention that As of PHP 8.0.0, if one of the operands cannot be interpreted a TypeError is thrown. which (if you ask me) is the correct thing to do

Hi @apokryfos, yeah, I don't want these kinds of bugs in the future. That's why I want to rectify this now while I'm doing the upgrade.

I think that PHP here has potentially revealed bugs in your code that were swept under the rug previously. You should never reach a situation where you're trying to round a non-numeric value so the problem is probably arising somewhere else, maybe you need to validate inputs somewhere else or otherwise sanitize data.

But still, the same pages/functions are working properly in the old PHP 5.4 server. So why I'm little confused with my new PHP 8.0.30 server.

Why is that confusing? Upgrades bring changes. Language features are altered. Mistakes which were tolerated or covered up by the language are not tolerated any more - this improves quality. Your code always had these potential bugs, but you got away with them. PHP is now making you write code in a better way. That's why these things are now errors in the new version. PHP 5.4 is now very obsolete. A lot has changed. Sometimes people find it's easier to rewrite their app than fix it, although yours sounds like an absolute monster if you have that many files.

Yes @ADyson, I understand. But do you believe that all the clients will agree to this and give us some more time to look into all those files? while in production how we can take such time and manually change every file?

You could make clear to your client what the situation is. It's not all that surprising that after 15 years of non-maintenance (?) you've now landed in upgrade-hell. Yii 1.1 is old, and I'm sure there are other old dependencies. I always prepare my clients to be ready to do a real overhaul of their code every 3 to 5 years, while doing minor updates in the mean time. 15 years is a very long time.

Yeah, absolutely. Will plan accordingly in the future.

If I was your client I would be asking why you hadn't upgraded the application before now, gradually over time, so that this crisis could have been avoided. It takes some investment but it's worth it in the long run. I appreciate not all clients have technical understanding but most will now be familiar in their personal lives with the fact that technology and software gets upgraded on a regular basis. So they probably had an expectation, even if it was unspoken, that the application would be kept up to date as well. They may even have assumed you were quietly doing that in the background.

Yeah. will try to explain them about this and looking forward to get some time.

Anyhow, PHP has Type Juggling feature in it already, right? I can't predict with this new upgrade why this Type Juggling not working as it is and produce an error.

Yes, PHP has type juggling, but there are things that can disable it. I already mentioned strict typing. Also, is it an error? Isn't it just a warning, or, as you write, an exception? Those are all very different things.

The code has not been edited for the strict_types enabled yet. I have updated my question with the error screen which I got now @KIKOSoftware

That "Unsupported operand types: string * int" would only occur if you actually try to multiply text that can't be automatically juggled to a numeric value. e.g. https://3v4l.org/EfKra#v8.0.30 . If the $_POST value in your screenshot were to contain a number it would work, even if the variable is technically a string - e.g. https://3v4l.org/6gjcm#v8.0.30 . So perhaps you need to add more validation to your code so it doesn't allow people to post non-numeric values in that field.

In PHP 5.4 such a situation would have just output 0 which, while not a crash, is also meaningless. Demo: https://3v4l.org/EfKra#v5.4.45 . So presumably in your old version, when this occurred it simply saved nonsense to the database instead of asking the user to enter proper data. This is certainly worth fixing.

Got it guys. Thanks for the clear explanation along with the examples. Will make corrections on my code side.

The

"Unsupported operand types: string * int"

error would only occur if you actually try to multiply text that can't be automatically juggled to a numeric value. e.g.
$x = "test" * 60;
echo $x;

Demo: https://3v4l.org/EfKra#v8.0.30 .
If the $_POST value in your screenshot were to contain a number it would work, even if the variable is technically a string - e.g.
$x = "30" * 60;
echo $x;

Demo: https://3v4l.org/6gjcm#v8.0.30 .
So I would suggest that to resolve this you need to add more validation to your code so it doesn't allow people to post non-numeric values in that field.
In PHP 5.4 such a situation would have just resulted in an output of 0 which, while not a crash, is also meaningless. Demo: https://3v4l.org/EfKra#v5.4.45 . So presumably in your old version, when this occurred it simply saved nonsense to the database instead of asking the user to enter proper data. This is certainly worth fixing.

Actually, those POST fields are optional number inputs. While the user enters the required input data then the form allows the user to submit it. That's why the POST field assumes an empty/null string. So, I'm going to use (float)$_POST['optional_input'] to fix this for now

That seems reasonable.
